# PHP: Convert str to number

Tags: php

For an unknown reason, I cant seem to be able to convert a string to a number. It always return 0. Here is the code:

```
$str = 'C$​2,313';
$str = str_replace(array("C$",","),"",$str);
echo $str.PHP_EOL;
echo intval($str);
exit;
```

The following always output:

```
​2313
0
```

How can I convert this string successfully to a number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a non-printable character between `$` and `2`. Try using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove all non-digit characters instead:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str);
echo $str.PHP_EOL;
echo intval($str);
```

Output:

```
2313
2313
```

Comment: How were you able to see that I have a "non-printable character"?

Comment: @PeterLur I copy pasted your question into https://3v4l.org/ and saw it as well. However upon saving it, it is removed.